# Managed Kiosk App from working Firebase/Firestore PWA getting permission problems

Tags: webview, google-chrome-app, progressive-web-apps, google-chrome-os, google-cloud-firestore

I have a working PWA at running at a URL like https://app.example.com/ and I'm trying to wrap it in a webview to ship to managed kiosks. We have been testing the app without authentication persistence and everything has been fine. Once presistance was added to the webview with `<webview partition="persist:example-kiosk" ...>` some queries to Firestore stopped working. Debugging the app shows the following error:

> Failed to load https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1beta1.Firestore/Listen/channel?gsessionid=...: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present`

How can I get Firestore working in a chrome app webview? Any chance google is working on a easier way to use PWAs as a managed kiosk app?

Comment: Can you clarify if the app is completely broken?  Or certain queries are completely broken?  Or some queries are intermittently broken?  An app that demonstrates the specific problem would be most helpful!  For what it's worth, I think that error can sometimes appear intermittently but without affecting the behavior of the app, since the client will generally automatically retry requests.  Though if you're using get(), that may be less helpful.